# How to turn off Scroll characters

Tags: terminal-emulator

When I use the mouse wheel to scroll up/down the Terminal window Linux all I get are some control characters being printed out. It looks like this..

```
^[OA^[OA^[OA^[OA^[OA^[OA^[OA^[OB^[OB^[OB^[OB^[OB^[OB^[OA^[OA^[OA^[OA
```

How can i Turn it off?

Comment: Not exactly a bash question - tag replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `tput rmcup`
like its described here https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2016/05/05/mouse-wheel-displaying-control-characters-in-a-terminal-or-scrolling-through-history-instead/

Answer (score 5):

You can use `tput reset` to reinitialize your terminal.